# Reading Android RGB light sensor - Galaxy S5

Tags: android, android-sensors, galaxy

I am using Java & Android Studio to read the light sensor information for Galaxy S5.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){
             currentReading = event.values[0];
//...

}

}
```

This gives me the lux value. Is it possible to read the individual values of the RGB light sensor in Galaxy S5 in order to get more information from it? I have looked into the Samsung SDK but I can't find this information (if any).
Update: 3 sensor data [0] (lux data) is times 200, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeLbE.png) is unchanged, [2] is times 200 to be of comparable value. Notice that the most sensible is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeLbE.png) but it moves independently from the others at times:
[image: 3 sensor data]

Comment: I do not know the answer, but is there anything in `event.values[1]`, by any chance?

Comment: Yes. there are 3 values (event.values.length is 3): [0]: 3.0, [1] 1596.0  [2] 1.0. The first is the lux I read, the second varies with the light (the value 1596.0 is at 0 lux), the third is a bit smaller but close to the first.

Comment: @MattGibson the 3 values are related to the light as they vary with it.

Comment: Android docs give only 1 value for this... Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT:
•values[0]: Ambient light level in SI lux units:   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the answer just to help anyone out there with a similar problem: on a Galaxy device with RGB light sensor there are 3 values returned: `event.values[0], event.values[1] and event.values[2]`. In the official Android documentation only the first is mentioned. After looking through the sensor pdf (“TMG3993, Gesture, Color, ALS, and Proximity Sensor Module with mobeam”, ams Datasheet, Available: http://ams.com/eng/content/view/download/349956), I found that it has an IR filter.

Therefore the RGB information from that sensor is to be found in  `event.values[1]` as it is the only one that does not change when targeted with infrared light. It is also the most sensitive of the 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same on my S5 and found out the following:

`values[0]` and `values[2]` seem to be LUX values, but they are WAY too high.
I compared them to my multimeter-luxmeter (Mastech ms8229), which is not a pure luxmeter but still somewhat reliable.
High values (1000+) were about double and [0] was always higher than [2].
I assume that one is filtered or normalized/corrected in some way.
And it is to assume that their inaccuracy is different from device to device, so without calibration they are a rough indication at best.
Also they drop below measured at low light conditions. At 50 Lux measured with the multimeter the sensor says 20.

`values[1]` seems to represent the light color in Kelvin but also very inaccurate. I have light sources from 2700K to 6500K in my place and they all were measured "ok" but depending on the distance a 4000K Philips LED bulb measured from 3900K to 3600K.

As to the graph posted in the question, i would say the [2] has to be [1] and the other 2 are [0] and [2] and if it was a regular light bulb and somewhat dim it would give a 2500K light with LUX at about 10 to 20. Assuming that in reality it could have been up to 50 Lux, which is totally ok to the eye, it all makes sense.

**important note**

From the light temperature you CAN calculate some RGB values but the sensor will have photodiodes that react to a specific wavelength of the light spectrum and that is the problem. If the light source has an odd or very small spectrum (LED, CFL) the sensor may be off more than it would be in sunlight or with incandescent light bulbs.

Unless someone can figure out how to access the sensor directly, the value is only what it is, light color and Lux.

I even took windows paint and made the entire screen 255 red and measured that, put the phone sensor right against the screen and then attempted to calculate "backwards". Did the same with 255 blue and green but the result was unusable.