# can someone help me with accessing RGB values on my smart-phone light sensor via Android studio?

Tags: android, android-sensors, samsung-galaxy, light-sensor

I am trying to take readings with the Ambient light sensor(TCS3407 Uncalibrated lux Sensor) on my samsung galaxys10+(sm-g975f). according to the driver info (https://github.com/ianmacd/d2s/blob/master/drivers/optics/tcs3407.h#L132) it should take red green and blue values. unless i am reading it wrong. However, the android documentation for ambient lightsensors states i can only get one argument ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQZ90.png)). This is my attempt access the ambient light sensor ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gOHq.png))

i know the thread ([Reading Android RGB light sensor - Galaxy S5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503627/reading-android-rgb-light-sensor-galaxy-s5)) exists but it doesnt clear up the question for me. I only have event.values[0] not [1]..[2] ect ect where as the driver documentation suggests i should have access to it

any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if anything needs to be clarified.

Comment: Just because the hardware can theoretically do it doesn't mean the OS is exposing that information